# Hive built-in functions not working

Tags: function, hadoop, hive, built-in

I'm using Hadoop 0.20.2 with Hive 0.11. I have succesfully inserted into hive/hdfs some csv-files in seperate tables. selects and joins work flawlessly. When trying to analyse some data, i needed to make use of the built in functions of hive like:

- substr
- to_date
- rand
- etc.

for example:

```
select sid, request_id, to_date(times), to_unix_timestamp(times) from contents where sid = '5000000032066010373';
```

*sid* and *request id* are strings here, *times* is a timestamp column
Unfortanetely i only get errors (always the same error stack) when using these functions:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:121)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFJSONTuple.<clinit>(GenericUDTFJSONTuple.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerGenericUDTF(FunctionRegistry.java:520)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DefaultUDFMethodResolver.getEvalMethod(DefaultUDFMethodResolver.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.initialize(GenericUDFBridge.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluators(Operator.java:970)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluatorsAndReturnStruct(Operator.java:996)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.initializeOp(FilterOperator.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:100)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
```

what am i doing wrong here?

```
SHOW FUNCTIONS;
```

shows me that these functions are in there ...

Comment: Can you check if you have jackson-core-asl-\*.\*.*.jar in your $HIVE_HOME/lib directory?

Comment: yes, version 1.8.8 is there ...

Comment: tried downgrading to hive 0.10.0, same error message

Comment: I think problem is that you have two jackson-core JARs (with different versions) on your classpath. One is located in HADOOP_HOME/lib and one is in HIVE_HOME/lib. Can you check it this is true ?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the jackson*.jar in your HADOOP_HOME/lib with the ones in HIVE_HOME/lib, restart Hadoop and try submitting the job.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem while using hive + apache hadoop 0.20.2

the problem is that hadoop-0.20.2 doesn't have these jackson jars in the lib folder, so either you add it manually in the hive console every time:

```
add jars $HIVE_HOME/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar;
```

or you copy all these jars to each machine in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

try updating the jackson*.jar in your HADOOP_HOME/lib with the ones in HIVE_HOME/lib, restart Hadoop and try submitting the job.

Thanks it worked